# What does $e^{2ix}$ and $e^{-2ix}$equal to?

Tags: trigonometry

What does $e^{2ix}$  and $e^{-2ix}$equal to?

Does it equal to $2\cos(x)+2i\sin(x)$ and $2\cos(x)-2i\sin(x)$?

Comment: In general, $e^{i\theta}$ equals $\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$.  See [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).  Therefore, $e^{2ix}=\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x)$, and since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are not linear, you can't bring the $2$'s outside.

Comment: Read as $e^{(2x)i}$ where $\theta=2x$

Comment: $e^{ix}= \cos x + i\sin x,  e^{2ix} = \cos(2x)+i\sin(2x), 2e^{ix} = 2\cos x + 2i\sin x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euler's formula states:

> $$ e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x $$

so
\begin{align*}
e^{2ix} &= e^{i(2x)} \\
&= \cos 2x + i \sin 2x
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
e^{-2ix} &= e^{i(-2x)} \\
&= \cos (-2x) + i \sin (-2x) \\
&= \cos 2x - i \sin 2x
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

No, but
$$
e^{\pm 2ix} = \cos 2x \pm i \sin 2x
$$